# PHP error log is packed with multiple \x{00} at beginning of log, using NGINX & PHP-FPM in Docker Container

Tags: nginx, docker, php-fpm, log-files

This is really just sort of an annoying behavior.  I have a Docker Container that includes:

NGINX, PHP-FPM and some other tools that I am using as a WebServer for a PHP web App, including a Laravel one, along with some other tools.  The non-Laravel app logs PHP NOTICES, WARNING, ERRORS to a log file.  It is "working", but in the log file is padding with a huge number of null bytes ? (\x{00}) when it is first created (3089725 chars).

In NGINX .conf I have:

```
access_log /nginx-home/logs/RIS-access.log;
error_log  /nginx-home/logs/RIS-error.log info;
```

and in other scripts I log to a different .log file by using:

```
ini_set("error_log", realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../') . "/php-error.log");
```

The log files are working, but the padding at the beginning adds about 4 MB of data to the log files.

I'd have to dig into the other settings for NGINX and php-fpm in my docker containers, but I am mostly using the default settings with a few adjustments to the php.ini file for large file uploads.  I think I am using the defaults in php-fpm.conf in docker.

The log files look something like this:

Padded with null bytes, followed by log entries:

```
[02-May-2021 08:42:10 America/Cayman] {
    "Called By:": "Controller.php",
    "Value:": "Action:  search_orthanc"
}
[02-May-2021 08:42:10 America/Cayman] {
    "Called By:": "DatabaseFactory.php",
    "Value:": {
        "Query:": "SELECT * from orthanc_hosts WHERE id = ?",
        "Params:": [
            "1"
        ]
    }
}
```

and they otherwise work fine.  The logging is mostly for development and debugging, but just wondering why they are padded like that and how to avoid that.

Also, the null bytes are all written to a single line in the log file.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm getting the same thing – https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67042680/nginx-log-full-of-null-characters. It seems like nobody can explain what causes this.